# CloudFlare for caching REST API response developed in core php

Tags: php, rest, caching, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I have developed REST API in core php. This APIs are used in mobile app to fetch data from server.

Now we have a situation where 10000 users are using the app at the same time. When all this users are on app at same time, the server(Amazon EC2 UBUNTU 12.04) fails.

In order to solve this, we have decided to use CloudFlare. After lot of research, it is still not clear how to use cloudflare to cache the response coming from APIs.

Below are few links that I have followed so far:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-

https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-advanced-caching/ .

We have already set CNAME and HOST details on our CloudFlare account. Can someone help me to know what implementation is needed. Or if this is possible at all or no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found that it is possible to cache the response of REST API. We just need to create a custom page rule.

Just in case someone else is facing the same issue then follow below steps:
1) Get the domain name for your URL. For example, if your API URL is http://xx.xx.xx.xx then you need to get a domain and link it so that your API URL can be http://domainname/...

2) Since the data is not HTML content or CSS, you should create a custom page rule. It is detailed very nicely by cloud flare but is hard to find the link. SO here is the link for the same: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000150272-How-do-I-use-Cache-Everything-with-Cloudflare-

The entire setup with Cloudflare is done and the performance of my server has improved drastically. We just need to follow the steps carefully!!!